# An open-source firewall or library capable of doing deep SSH inspection?

Tags: open-source, network-monitor, packet-capture, content-filtering

[I'm looking to build a firewall that will perform "man-in-the-middle" inspections on SSH traffic](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/175756/how-ssh-deep-inspection-works). It will decrypt, inspect and re-encrypt traffic.  There are quite a few free solutions for SSL deep inspection that do this, but none for SSH.

I am particularly interested in the ability to do fine grained filtering of applications and commands (like preventing a user from launching a remote web browser through X11 over SSH).

Open source dpi tools include nDPI, Libprotoident, and Netifyd but I don't think they have this feature.

Comment: So, you have the SSH credentials/etc of everyone going through, if I understand correctly?

Comment: yes, but I've been doing some reading and it seems like these man-in-the-middle [solutions](http://phoneboy.org/2015/07/29/lies-damn-lies-and-inspecting-ssh-traffic-securely/) are [really bad practice](http://phoneboy.org/2015/07/30/the-right-way-to-inspect-ssh-connections/)